# How to define functions in Child Context Provider from Parent Context Provider in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I'm new to react and I'm facing issue in the Context API using

> ***React Functional Components***

For example I have a scenario where I need to split the authentication providers based on the host since all of them have different way of authentication logic.

I have following child providers:

i. `ChildHostProviderA`

ii. `ChildHostProviderB`

iii. `ChildHostProviderC`

iv. `ChildHostProviderD`

I need to switch the authentication providers from the parent provider  based on where the application is.

What I have done is created a generic Context Provider (`ParentHostProvider`) which will be switched based on the host it is in. The generic context provider will have these functions:

1. GetAccessToken()
2. SignIn()
3. SingOut()

If I need these functions to be implemented in the Child Providers then what is the best way to do in React?

I've tried finding many resources online but couldn't find one, any help regarding this scenario would be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the app is deployed on different hosts and the authentication logic changes according to the host.

If it is the case, you don't need to involve context in this logic, as it will never change for a host. It is more related to Javascript than React.

You can create a file called `authenticationFunctions.js` with all your different functions logic **organized by hostname**. Like this:

```js
export default {
  "host1.dev": {
    getAccessToken: () => {
      console.log("host1 get access token");
    },
    signIn: () => {
      console.log("host1 sign in");
    },
    signOut: () => {
      console.log("host1 sign out");
    }
  },
  "759ee.codesandbox.io": {
    getAccessToken: () => {
      console.log("codesandbox.io get access token");
    },
    signIn: () => {
      console.log("codesandbox.io sign in");
    },
    signOut: () => {
      console.log("codesandbox.io sign out");
    }
  }
};
```

And after that in your provider you will select the correct functions according to the hostname and pass it to the provider

```js
import React, { useContext } from "react";
import authenticationFunctions from "./authenticationFunctions";
const UserContext = React.createContext(null);

const hostname = window.location.hostname;
let funs = authenticationFunctions[hostname];
if (!funs) {
  console.error("There is no authenticationFunctions for this host");
}

export default function UserProvider({ children }) {
  return (
    <UserContext.Provider value={funs || {}}>{children}</UserContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

Here is a Codesandbox demonstrating this: https://codesandbox.io/s/authentication-logic-change-according-to-host-759ee?file=/src/UserProvider.js:156-329

Comment: Thanks @abumalick that really helps

Comment: You are welcome! Please vote for the answer and mark it as accepted on the left of the answer if it fixed your problem.